# QtCreator : set device-debug to WLAN-SSH without USB

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am working on/with Ubuntu-phone / Ubuntu-Touch on my Gnex in VMware.

VMware seems to have USB-Problems so I got problems with `adb/usb/ssh` too.

But I am connected to the phone by WLAN-SSH.

Is it possible to configure the 'device' in Creator  to WLAN-SSH without having USB-Connection to the phone?

regards
sUbuPack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but right now a little bit tricky.

1. Get the IP-address of your Ubuntu Touch device.

   ```
   adb shell 
   ip addr show wlan0
   ```
2. edit the file `menu.json`

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/menu.json
   ```

   remove there 'p2222' and change 127.0.0.1 to the IP-Address from (1.)

Restart the QT-Creator and run your application with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

I tried it with my N7 and it worked.

Problems:

1. You have to connect via USB to get your mobiles IP address. (I don't know how we can figure out on the mobile itself)
2. You have to change the file `menu.json` every time the IP-address changes.

Comment: thanks!! sudo nano /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/menu.json is the file I was looking for!!